# Python | Как очистить лист от ботов? [discord.py]

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Проблема в том, что боты из листа не очищаются.

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def random(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.send("Ребята, которых выбрал бот:")
    winnerslist = []
    num = 0 
    for i in range(amount):
        winmember = ctx.guild.members
        winmember.pop(winmember.index(bot.user))
        winners = rrandom.choice(winmember)
        role1 = ctx.guild.get_role(850398755017588797)
        if role1 in winners.roles:
            pass
        else:
            num += 1
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(850398755017588797) 
            await winners.add_roles(role)
            winnerslist.append(str(num) + ". " + winners)

    await ctx.send('\n'.join(str(x) for x in winnerslist))
```

Исход:

[image]

P.S Не хочется прописывать ещё 1 `if` потому, что теряется кол-во пользователей в исходе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В любом случае нужно заранее сделать проверку, еще перед формированием списка пользователей.

Создавая `winmember`, нужно не присвоить список всех пользователей, а отсортировать, чтобы там не было ботов. Это можно сделать через проверку условия `member.bot == False` или `not member.bot`.

**Заменяем эту строку**

```
winmember = ctx.guild.members
```

**На эту**

```
winmember = [member for member in ctx.guild.members if member.bot == False]
```

---

Эта строка больше не нужна, так как ботов в списке уже в принципе нет.
Все, что она делала - удаляла из списка только вашего бота.

```
winmember.pop(winmember.index(bot.user))
```